# Command key as Meta key in OS X Terminal.app

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

When i unckeck the *'Use option as meta key'* box in Settings, and then
do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (which i want to mean <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for forward-word in bash) Terminal gives me a 'find word' popup, which isn't what i want. What i really want is for my Terminals to behave just like an xterm w.r.t. the key
bindings. Is there any way to disable this popup and its binding?

I know i could just use actual xterms, but for a variety of reasons i want to use Terminal.

thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 42):

The `option as meta key` selection has no effect on the **Command** (Apple) key.  If `option as meta key` is selected, then the **Option** key acts as a **Meta** key in `bash` and elsewhere; just press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  If you de-select it, there is no **Meta** key.  (In either case, some command line programs may recognize the traditional <kbd>ESC</kbd>+char sequence as **Meta**  char.)

If you are running OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), Apple supplies a built-in way to change the meaning of the keyboard modifier keys, including **Command** and **Option**.  Go to `System Preferences -> Keyboard` and click on the `Modifier Key...` button.  A panel will appear that allows you to, for instance, swap the meaning of the **Option** and **Command** keys.  But, be warned that this is a global option and will apply *everywhere* on OS X and could lead to some major confusion.  If you do that, you will be swimming upstream as noted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/21579/terminal-app-does-not-support-alt-meta-command-key-modifiers-such-as-meta-backspa).  You will likely be best served long-term by getting used to the OS X default of using the **Option** key as **Meta** and, if necessary, restoring application defaults (for `Emacs`, say) to follow that convention.

FURTHER EDIT:  This [blog post](http://andrewmcdermott.blogspot.com/2009/11/cmd-key-happy-swap-cmdalt-keys-in.html) and [program](http://github.com/aim-stuff/cmd-key-happy) (untested) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there *any* way make the Command key behave as Meta in Terminal?

Comment: See added second paragraph above.

Comment: I just ran across something else that might actually do what you want to do; see further edit above.

Comment: If the `option as meta key` is not selected, then the default meta key in Terminal.app is ESC. From `man bash` on OS X 10.6: "On keyboards without a meta key, M-x means ESC x, i.e., press the Escape key then the x key."

Comment: With `Use option as meta key checked`, how do I type pipe "|" and tilde "~" on a Macbook Pro with a French keyboard?

Comment: I've had some success doing the same with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). It works well and can do lots of things, but can be tricky to configure if not just using the standard swap templates.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the `Meta` key being `ESC` if `ESC` wasn't on the damn touch bar!

Answer (score 9):

Just install keyremap4macbook utility from http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/ .

In the option, you can tweak Terminal.app many ways, not to mention Option to Command_L mapping and vice versa. It has so many handy options that i would say this is a must app for mac user!

Comment: Now known as Karabiner.

Comment: Karabiner works great. There are many pre-defined behaviours, including swapping Cmd and Option only in Terminal, and doing so even except for some key combinations: Cmd-Tab, Cmd-backtick, and Cmd-space, which one often wants to still be captured by Finder. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: I just realised this answer hasn't answered how to customise key mapping for the meta key. I hope however this answer might help others to find the meta key on a Mac though (it took me ages to find the meta key on Mac and this forum just helped me - so posting what I've got here. No harm I guess).

On my Macbook Pro (el capitan), the meta key is by default mapped to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

For example, say in emacs editor, to do a `M-%` ([emacs find and replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html)), I would do <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>

(I've tested this on iTerm2 and Terminal app.)

The answer posted by @NedDeily helped.