# can't input '<' in ipython/python shell

Tags: python, shell, ipython, readline

I installed IPython and readline through pip like this:

`sudo pip install ipython`

`sudo pip install readline`

but I find that I can't input '<' in either Python shell or IPython shell. When I type '<' my mac would alarm.

I think this may be related to `readline` because when I remove readline from my computer it works okay and I can type '<' in shell.

I'm using macbook pro, iTerm2, 10.8.3, python2.7.2

Comment: You might want to take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726449/installing-ipython-with-readline-on-the-mac

Comment: I tried every method but none works...

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print sys.stdin.readline()
```

and do:

```
python2 script.py < script.py
```

and you should get the contents of your own file :)

Comment: you didn't get my point... I mean that I can't type '<' in shell. Like in IPython: In[1]: (I type <, nothing typed in and my mac alarms that I press the wrong button.)

Comment: Have you tried a different terminal emulator?

Comment: MAC... why the bloody f*** didn't you say so.. I'm outahere *poff*.. You'll have to tell your terminal to not treat < as a command character. This has nothing what so ever to do with Python sorry to say (i own a mac, for a very specific project, other than that.. it's a expensive junk to write anything except facebook updates on). Here try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856437/command-key-as-meta-key-in-os-x-terminal-app

Comment: Previous comment is intended partially as humor, i'm aware that you sad you're using a mac (i just missed it obviously)